# Animate custom button using ViewStateManager

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager

I'm working on a custom button for my project.
I'm not using a default `Button` but just a `ContentControl` with a `ControlTemplate` assigned to it.

For the beginning just a simple template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MySampleTemplate">
    <Image x:Name="img" Source="/AppName;component/Res/Img/normalstate.png" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now I would like to animate the image by using `VisualStateManager`.
First I created a "Hover" and a "Normal" state:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MySampleTemplate">
    <Image x:Name="img" Source="/AppName;component/Res/Img/normalstate.png">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState Name="Hover">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="img" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="/AppName;component/Res/Img/hoverstate.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Image>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In Code behind:

```
btnSampleButton.MouseEnter += (s,e) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, "Hover", false);
btnSampleButton.MouseLeave += (s,e) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, "Normal", false);
```

Everything works just fine. If I hover over the button `hoverstate.png` is shown and if I don't hover over `normalstate.png` is shown.
Now I would like to animate `LeftMouseButtonDown` and `LeftMouseButtonUp` to achieve a pressing animation if the user click on the button.

I created a `VisualState` called "Pressed" and just set it up like "Hover" (just replaced hoverstate.png with pressedstate.png).
In the code behind I did this:

```
btnSampleButton.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s,e) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, "Pressed", false);
btnSampleButton.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s,e) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, btnSampleButton.IsMouseOver ? "Hover" : "Normal", false);
```

However it does not work. `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` work fine but I can't see any changes to the button if I press/release my left mouse button.

Do you have any advice to get it work?

Edit:
Control:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="btnSampleButton" Template="{StaticResource SamplButtonTemplate}" />
```

ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SamplButtonTemplate">
    <Image x:Name="Image" Source="/AppName;component/Res/Img/normalstate.png">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState Name="Hover">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="/AppName;component/Res/Img/hoverstate.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="/AppName;component/Res/Img/pressedstate.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Image>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
btnSampleButton.MouseEnter += (s, e) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, "Hover", false);
btnSampleButton.MouseLeave += (s, e) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, "Normal", false);
btnSampleButton.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown +=
            (s, e) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, "Pressed", false);
btnSampleButton.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp +=
            (s, e) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, btnSampleButton.IsMouseOver ? "Hover" : "Normal", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>`MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` gets swallowed by `Click` event of Button that's why these events are never raised for button and no change in VisualState.</s>

Instead hook corresponding Preview events i.e. **`PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`** and **`PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`** :

```
btnSampleButton.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s,e) => 
          VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, "Pressed", false);

btnSampleButton.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += (s,e) => 
      VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnSampleButton, btnSampleButton.IsMouseOver ?
                                                      "Hover" : "Normal", false);
```

Remove **`FillBehavior="Stop"`** from second StoryBoard and your code works fine.

```
<VisualState Name="Pressed">
   <Storyboard>
     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0"
                                    FillBehavior="Stop" <-- Remove this
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Image" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I edited my question and included the whole source.

Comment: Ah very nice thanks :) But I have another question: Everything works now but if I press the left mouse button it takes about 1 sec until the button image changes to hoverstate.png. Do you know why this may happen?